# Can two or more separate image files be used

Tags: texturing, uv

Is it possible to use two or more separate image files for the objects texture (on the unwrapped object) and if so what is the procedure?

As an example consider that a plank of wood has an 'end grain' (can contain growth rings of the timber) which looks different from the 'face grain'.

Thanks

Comment: The simplest way to do what you're saying is to use two different materials, one for the face grain and one for the end grain.  Assign faces to either of those two materials and define those materials using two different images.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your fast reply. Yes I assumed that two (or more) different materials are required BUT how do you open two different image files (I am assuming this is done via Materials Properties>Open Image and when I attempt to do that it seems that only one image can be opened OR do you open one image, apply to surfaces required and then open another image and apply to other surfaces?)

Comment: You edit each material separately, by selecting the material from the list of those on the object.  Each material is independent of the others.  I would recommend looking at some tutorials for learning "blender nodes".

Comment: Hi arnold I would suggest you to use nodes by going to shading workspace.
it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks I will look at using nodes first looking for Youtube tutorials. At least now I know where to start. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this by using nodes e.g. if you want different images/textures depending on coordinates like this:

[image]

or....if you want different images/textures per face, you create two materials for the object like this:

[image]

then go to edit mode, face select, select the face and the material you want to assign to that face and then press "assign"

result:
[image]

of course, instead of simple colors you would connect your image texture.

If you need further more detailed explanation, just let me know.

Comment: @john arnold you can also mix the images procedurally using noises or manipulating those coordinates but, I think you should go through some basic tutorials before.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the detailed method. i will give it a go and see what I can apply although it is becoming a lot more 'technical' than what I know at this point being very new to not only Blender but also 3d modelling. I will just keep 'chipping' at learning.